# Java - how to get maximum result of a calculation

Tags: java

We are working on creating object and driver classes. I have an object class that does various things to a moving exploratory robot.

What I need to do now is create a method that returns the largest distance that the robot moved in one single move command. I also need to return the time that it took to move that distance.

Here's the relevant code for that so far:

```
{

private int xcoord, ycoord; //Cartesian coordinates of the robot
private int identification; //Identification number of the robot
private double rate; //Rate at which the robot explores
private double traveled; //Distance the robot has travelled
private double timeSpent; //Time spent travelling
private double longestLeg; //Longest leg of the journey
private double longestLegTime; //Time on the longest leg

//Sets up a robot with the given ID number and beginning x and y coordinates
public Robot (int id, int x, int y) 
{
  identification = id;
  xcoord = x;
  ycoord = y;
  traveled = 0;
  rate = 5.0;
}

//Has the robot travel to the set coordinates
public double setDestination (int x, int y)
{
  double distance = Math.pow(x - xcoord, 2) + Math.pow(y - ycoord, 2);
  traveled += Math.sqrt(distance);
  xcoord = x;
  ycoord = y;
  timeSpent += Math.sqrt(distance)/rate;

  return traveled;
}

//Gets the time spent travelling
public double getTimeSpent()
{
  return timeSpent;
}


//Sets the rate at which the robot travels
public void setRate(double setrate)
{
  rate = setrate;
}

//Returns longest leg of the robot's travels
public int getLongestLeg()
{
  return longestLeg;
}

//Returns time of longest leg
public double getLongestLegTime()
{
  return longestLegTime;
}
```

I'm not allowed to use if statements or loops yet, so it will have to be using Math.max I'm guessing. I tried using it, but it gave me an error saying that it required an int but I supplied a double.

Any suggestions would be awesome. Thanks!

If you are able, I have one final problem with the code as well. I need to create a method that would get the distance between two Robot objects. I'm not even sure how to start this one since we haven't really worked with it yet. A suggestion on how to even start this would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: Please remove your extra code and only show the minimal amount of code needed to answer the question.  For example, your getters is just extra code that does not add to the problem.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I left those getters in specifically because I thought they might be relevant...especially since the question was specifically about it returning the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid casting, this should work:

```
longestLeg = Math.max(distance, longestLeg);
```

If you are getting an error about requiring an int, it probably means one of your parameters was an int when it shouldn't be. Can't be sure without seeing exactly how you were calling it, but I suspect it may have been to do with the fact getLongestLeg() is returning longestLeg as an int when it's actually a double. I would suggest changing that method to:

```
//Returns longest leg of the robot's travels
public double getLongestLeg()
{
  return longestLeg;
}
```

In terms of your second question, to calculate the distance between another robot, the calcDist() method should probably look something like this:

```
   public double calcDist(Robot other)
    {
      return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.getX() - other.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(this.getY() - other.getY(), 2));
    }
```

Comment: Ah okay, that worked for me. That might have just been a mistake on my part.

Problem now is that it is returning the whole distance traveled, not an individual leg. Any other suggestions for that?

Comment: Where are you setting the longest leg?

Comment: Got it fixed. I had it as Math.max(traveled, longestLeg). I changed traveled to the squareroot of distance and it worked fine.
Do you happen to have any suggestion to get me started on the last part of the question (getting the distance between two different robot objects)?

Comment: You'll need some new methods for getting the position of the Robot, like getX() and getY(). Then you can use the same formula you use to get the distance currently but on the two robots positions:
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(robot1.getX() - robot2.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(robot1.getY() - robot2.getY(), 2));

Comment: Here's the specific instructions:

By adding a “calcDist” method to the Robot class as well as a “getX” and a “getY” method, you should now be able to add a line of code that queries one of the two robot objects for its position and then uses the calcDist method of the other object to determine the current distance between the two robots and prints it out. No variables should be added to the driver class that store the location of either robot, nor should code to compute the distance between two points be added to the driver class.

Comment: I updated my original solution with a possible implementation of calcDist(), would have got a bit messy to put it in the comments :)

Comment: I'm not sure how the self and other components of that code would work...could you explain that? As it's written, it says that it cannot find the variables "self" and "other"

Comment: Woops, that was my mistake, getting my languages mixed up. 'self' should have been 'this', which just references the robot class itself. Hopefully working now?

Comment: *almost* working haha. I must have messed up typing somewhere because my numbers are off from what they are supposed to be, but I should be able to figure it out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right you just wanted to use the Math.max() with Integers.

Try

```
(int) Math.max()
```

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. The error is when I try to return longestLeg. Even typecasting is that way doesn't make it work.